# If a post I edited gets downvoted, will I lose reputation too?

Tags: support, edits, reputation, downvotes

The question title pretty much says it all. What would happen if I edited some user's post on Stack Overflow and said post gets downvoted? Would both the original poster and I lose reputation, or would only the OP be affected?
Theoretically, the post is a product of the OP and of my edits, so would that qualify said post as also mine and thus take reputation away from my account?

Comment: No, you won't .

Comment: "Theoretically, the post is a product of the OP and of my edits, so would that qualify said post as also mine" license wise that's true. The edited post is a derived work with both of you as shared authors. The reputation doesn't really reflect that here on SO. You don't lose but you also don't gain any reputation from edits. If you edit, you only are in it for the greater good.

Comment: *"You don't lose but you also don't gain any reputation from edits"* Not quite true, @Trilarion . As a user with < 2k reputation, you get 2 reputation for each accepted/approved edit suggestion and can earn up to a maximum of 1,000 reputation this way.

Comment: @Larnu As _any_ user you can get 2 reputation for each accepted/approved edit suggestion and can earn up to a max of 1,000 reputation that way. The only difference is that users with >2k and <20k can only suggest edits on tag wikis/excerpts (and users with more rep than that need to have edits approved that were suggested prior to reaching 20k)

Comment: Editors are editors, not authors.

Comment: You will re-lose the gained '+2' from your accepted Edit if the "Post" (= Question (=> Thread)) gets roomba'd...

Comment: If your edit made the post worse and resulted in those extra downvotes, the edit should not have been accepted. Mind you, if the edit made the post more clear and more obviously deserving of downvotes... Well I guess that's still not your problem.